ng test - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
Recently, I upgraded my angular project from v14 to v15. But after the upgrade, on running the test suite using the command ng test, I'm getting the following error:

I addressed the warning shown in the above screenshot but unfortunately, the issue didn't get resolved. Please help me in any way possible and let me know in case more details are needed.
For reference,
package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.10",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "auth0-js": "^9.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "material-icons": "^1.13.12",
    "ngx-mat-multi-sort": "^0.7.4",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^3.3.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^16.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.11",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "13.5.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.2.10",
    "@types/auth0-js": "^9.21.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "ng-packagr": "^15.2.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^1.20.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "glob-parent": "^5.1.2",
    "set-value": "^4.0.1",
    "ansi-regex": "^5.0.1"
  }

karma.conf.js
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('karma-spec-reporter'),
            require('karma-junit-reporter'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
        ],
        client: {
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage'),
            reports: ['text-summary', 'cobertura'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
            combineBrowserReports: true,
            'report-config': {
                cobertura: {
                    // the default, but better to be explicit
                    file: 'cobertura-coverage.xml'
                }
            },
        },
        files: [
            'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
        ],
        junitReporter: {
            outputDir: './reports',
            outputFile: 'junit.xml',
            useBrowserName: false
            // nameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the name attribute in xml testcase element
            // classNameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the classname attribute in xml testcase element
            // properties: {}, // key value pair of properties to add to the <properties> section of the report
            /// xmlVersion: null // use '1' if reporting to be per SonarQube 6.2 XML format
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'spec', 'coverage-istanbul', 'junit'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
        customLaunchers: {
            ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
                base: 'ChromeHeadless',
                flags: ['--no-sandbox']
            }
        },
        singleRun: false,
        restartOnFileChange: true
    });
};


Does this help : https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/3417 ?

Already looked at that, I don't have the .babelrc file, so don't know where to add the plugin mentioned in that solution.

Can you provide the package.json , the karma conf and the test that you're trying to run ?

@ArnaudFlaesch, I've added them now above, please check.

Thanks, please also add one of the spec files you try to run

Apology, I'm not allowed to share it.

Ok no problem, maybe try to setup a separate angular 15 project and compare the configs, and/or re-check the migration guide just in case.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
